# Android Rotated Webview

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I have rotated a webview by 90 degrees but now the rotated webview is not taking up the full height. The rotated height seems the old width. The web content still fit in. I have inherited from a webview and overridden the onDraw method

```
canvas.Translate(0, this.Height);
canvas.Rotate(-90);
canvas.ClipRect(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, Region.Op.Replace);
base.OnDraw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly solution but just in case...

Did you try using `="fill_parent"` in your axml file?